# nodejs restarting pm2 with flightplan

Tags: node.js, pm2

I'm using flightplan to deploy my app and pm2 to manage the node servers. All commands are working at a CLI level but fail when running with flightplan.

Flightplan command:

```
remote.sudo('pm2 stop 0');
```

Gives me the following error when running flightpath:

```
[PM2] Stopping 0
[PM2][error] Process 0 not found
```

Running pm2 in the CLI gives me the following output:

```
┌───────────┬────┬──────┬──────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬─────────────┬──────────┐
│ App name  │ id │ mode │ pid  │ status │ restart │ uptime │ memory      │ watching │
├───────────┼────┼──────┼──────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼─────────────┼──────────┤
│ sphinxapi │ 0  │ fork │ 6579 │ online │ 3       │ 0s     │ 11.887 MB   │ disabled │
└───────────┴────┴──────┴──────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴─────────────┴──────────┘
```

When I run pm2 stop 0 it closes the node server as expected. Any ideas why flightplan gives  the error it can't find the process?

---

I added a bash script to call the command and it works fine at CLI level ./pm2restart.sh but the same result happens when I call the script from flightplan it says the process cannot be found. This is true when calling the App Name or id

Comment: Are you running PM2 CLI as sudo and your script as sudo ?

Comment: from the flightplan output its running the command as sudo, in the CLI I'm also running 'sudo pm2 stop 0'. It works fine in CLI just errors when flightplan tries to run the command

Comment: Try to use the pid or the App name instead of the id.
example:
remote.sudo('pm2 stop sphinxapi')

Comment: @MohamedAmjadLASRI yes I've tried this but the same result, it works at CLI level but not when flightpath tries to execute it

Comment: Have you tried `pm2 stop all`? Just curious what the output would be there. If it doesn't pick anything up there then maybe the command is running as a different user to the one that started the app?

Comment: ok I've gotten a little further if I run remote.exec('pm2 stop 0'); instead of remote.sudo it stops the server fine but starting it again starts the server in PM2 but nothing is actually running the browser remote.exec('sudo pm2 start "/usr/bin/npm" --name "sphinxapi" -f -- start'); but always the command works fine at CLI level